# Excel -Macro- To Copy & Paste Data Based On Date Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have found the following code and it works great; however, I have to manually change the month so it goes to the right sheet on the second workbook. As the sheets are in months, how can I make it change automatically to the current month?

```
Sub AlarmSheet()
Dim wkb As Workbook, wks As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
Dim FilePath As String, FileName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet, blnOpened As Boolean

'Change these variables as desired...
FilePath = "B:\CARECENT\28 Day\" 'change path here
FileName = "Installs_Removals_2016.xlsm" 'change name here
    Call ToggleEvents(False)
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHA") 'change source sheet name here
If WbOpen(FileName) = True Then
    Set wkb = Workbooks(FileName)
    blnOpened = False
Else
    If Right(FilePath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then
        FilePath = FilePath & Application.PathSeparator
    End If
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath & FileName)
    blnOpened = True
End If
Set wks = wkb.Sheets("June") 'change destination sheet name here
LastRow = wks.Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=wks.Cells(1, 1), searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
wks.Cells(LastRow, "A").Value = ws.Cells(63, "B").Value
wks.Cells(LastRow, "B").Value = ws.Cells(6, "B").Value
wks.Cells(LastRow, "C").Value = ws.Cells(7, "B").Value
wks.Cells(LastRow, "I").Value = ws.Cells(9, "B").Value '& "," & ws.Cells(10, "B").Value & "," & ws.Cells(11, "B").Value
wks.Cells(LastRow, "J").Value = ws.Cells(10, "B").Value
wks.Cells(LastRow, "N").Value = ws.Cells(11, "B").Value
wks.Cells(LastRow, "O").Value = ws.Cells(15, "B").Value
wks.Cells(LastRow, "P").Value = ws.Cells(60, "B").Value

If blnOpened = True Then
wkb.Close SaveChanges:=True
End If
'If MsgBox("Clear values?", vbYesNo, "CLEAR?") = vbYes Then
    'Call ClearData
End If
Call ToggleEvents(True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Giving credit to @Jason Brady I feel it will be better to declare a variable for example ~Dim shnew As String
shnew = Format(Date, "mmmm")~ Then use shnew in Set wks line.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace "June" with `Format(Date, "mmmm")` and this will give you just the month of the current date.